# Angular 7 CanActivate Guard for URL

Tags: angular, url, guard

I'm trying to create a Guard for specific URL. I would like to check in Guard if my url contain a param called "id". If yes, I would like to redirect to specific url with this id and id value, if not I would like to run method from service which will create an id and set it to URL.

I have attached canActivate to my routes. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on creation rest of logic of the Guard. I know that there is something like UrlTree which I can reuse. Can anyone help with creating this kind of Guard? I have also added comments in my code. Thanks a lot.

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<UrlTree> {
      const createContract = from(this._service.createNewContract());

      if(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['id']) {
      //Here I would like to check if my URL has a param "id", then I should allow user to enter.
      }
      //In case there is no such param with any value, I need to run method from service which in response will give me an id value, and I need to attach it to current URL with ?id={value}.
```

Comment: So is this for a single route only?

Comment: Yes, as for now this is for single route only.

Comment: Hmm.. also a bit unclear. You say in question: `I would like to check in Guard if my url contain a param called "id". If yes, I would like to redirect to specific url` but in your guard you say `Here I would like to check if my URL has a param "id", then I should allow user to enter.` So which is it, you like to redirect or like to let user enter the page?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the service responsible to give you the ID is named "getIdService" and the method is named "getId", I would do it like this:

```js
  constructor(private router: Router, private getIdService: SomeService) {}

  async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

      if(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['id'] != null) { // id 0 is valid
        return true;
      }

    // here get your ID from your service
    this.getIdService.getId().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((id: number) => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('yourURL?id=' + id)
    });

    return false;
  }
```

Hope it helps.